# Programmatically make color filled UIBarButtonItem

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uibutton, uikit

I have a `UIBarButtonItem` with the `UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch` type. I can programmatically change the tint color, like so:

```
searchButton.tintColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
```

However, what I'm trying to do is figure out a way to programmatically "fill" the button (i.e. the magnifying glass) with a given color. More generally, I'm trying to use a change in the icon to indicate that the search functionality is active.

I really like the built in search icon, but the lack of an obvious fill functionality is annoying. Is there any way to do something like this without creating an entirely custom button/icon? If not, what's the easiest way to utilize the existing search icon to create a custom button that *does* have the ability to be filled?

Answer (score 0):

First off I would suggest simply using the `tintColor` to show your selected/unselected states without trying to mess with the shape itself since it is much easier and will convey what you're trying to do. Keep in mind that in this specific case, the magnifying glass may not even look right if it is filled in, that shape is very specific and people are used to seeing empty space in the circle.

If you want to continue on that route though, no you cannot easily change the built-in search icon. Your options are 1. programmatically take a snapshot of such an icon on the screen and try to manipulate that using CoreGraphics (not a great solution) or the better solution 2. which is just to get/make your own image and then you don't have to do any of it programmatically.